# Display a loading image as long as a jquery function is executing

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, loading

I m working on a Spring MVC java web application . The app contains a JSP page , on it I have a table in which I display data from the DB. The data is diplayed in text inputs which belong to the class .editable
I implemented a script that does the following :
-select the text inputs from the table , 
-create a span with the data from the text inputs
-hides the text input

```
function editableInput() {
$('.editable').each(function() {
var input = $(this);
input.before("<span class='spanEditable'>" + input.val() + "</span>");
input.hide();
});
}
```

I later use a script to display the text input for a row , when the row is selected from a radio input.
All of this for making a good looking table that permits CRUD operations , on a row , when the row is selected , when no row is selected , it displays all the table content like plain text , not using a text input.

The problem i am facing : When the page is loading it displays all the table rows like it is initially made , with all the data in text inputs , after the script is being completed all the data is displayed in the spans. This looks really bad , until all the stuff is loaded.

How can i use a loading gif , until the function editableInput()  is completed ?
If i would use a AJAX call i would know how to add the loading gif , but this is how i`m calling the function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
editableInput(); )};
```

Comment: how are you populating the data initially into inputs? from java or in the browser?

Comment: I`m sending an ArrayList from a controller and i`m using a <c:for each> loop in the JSP page to populate the inputs from the table with data from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You may experiment with **[jQuery BlockUI Plugin (v2)](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)**

Comment: thanks , this would work , but i don`t want to disable the whole page , i would just like to hide the table div , until the function that i wrote executes , and showing a loading .gif image during that , until the table is loaded properly

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though this would work , i don't like the look of it , I really want to use the well known ajax-loading.gif image

Comment: You may experiment with the CSS

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this one, though rather crude but will work. On loading the page wrap your table into another div using:

```
$("table#table1").wrap("<div id='dvWrapp' style='background-color:#000;'/>");
```

then after completing the `editableInput`  call just unwrap it:

```
$("table#table1").unwrap();
```

You can set style for the wrapper div to show loading image or some message also.

Please try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/FkjkR/

Comment: I have just tried the first line you suggested and what it does is this : -in hmtl code it wrappes the table with a div with background:black; style  <div><table></table></div> but the table is still visible

Comment: you needed to work with the CSS for div. but as blockUI works for you it is good.

Comment: what should i change in the css for the div , so that the table is not visible ? blockui works , but i would prefer a "lighter" animation , like a small loading-gif

Comment: very sorry for the delay. hope this still helps you. please have a look at the fiddle.